# JQuery UI Autocomplete with categories and scrollbar

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, scrollbars

I'm having trouble using autocomplete with categories and then adding a vertical scrollbar. When the list is shorter than the max-height the scrollbar does not show just like expected. But when the last item in the list is selected the scrollbar appears.

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/youone/ajjz4h53/) (taken right off the demo page, type "a" in the input)

Any clues on how to solve this?

```
$.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
  _create: function() {
    this._super();
    this.widget().menu( "option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)" );
  },
  _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
    var that = this,
      currentCategory = "";
    $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
      var li;
      if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
        ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
        currentCategory = item.category;
      }
      li = that._renderItemData( ul, item );
      if ( item.category ) {
        li.attr( "aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label );
      }
    });
  }
});

var data = [
  { label: "anders", category: "" },
  { label: "andreas", category: "" },
  { label: "antal", category: "" },
  { label: "annhhx10", category: "Products" },
  { label: "annk K12", category: "Products" },
  { label: "annttop C13", category: "Products" },
  { label: "anders andersson", category: "People" },
  { label: "andreas andersson", category: "People" },
  { label: "andreas johnson", category: "People" }
];

$( "#search" ).catcomplete({
  delay: 0,
  source: data
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself. A little padding on the ul-element did the trick.